# Process builder Default Currency

Tags: process-builder

I have created a process builder , wherein one of the field is of type currency and I am using it in the Entry Criteria in the process builder. The value which I put in defaults to currency : $, whereas I need to use the currency : Euro.
I have tried using €500,  EUR 500, it says invalid value.

Kindly suggest as to how to change the currency to Euro.

Comment: Is your org multi-currency enabled? Have you tried running the flow in the context of a user whose locale would have the euro as their default currency?

Comment: note: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpupAAC (albeit for workflow, not process builder). You could use a compound entry criteria `currencyIsoCode = 'EUR' and amount > 500`